# How do you enforce which class file a Java application should use?

Tags: java, file, structure

I am trying to call a constructor for an object called Supplier, but the wrong Supplier.java file is being used.

I have separated my application into two "packages" part 1 and part 2. Each with their own version of Supplier.

When I run application 2 in package "part 2" the Supplier.java in **part 1** is being used. How do I resolve this? Below is an image of the file structure.

Note: the Constructors have **different method signatures**

[image: file structure]

Here is an example of the call to the Supplier Constructor made in application 2:

```
allSuppliers.add(new Supplier(supplierName,supplierAddress,supplierProductList,supplierRegion));
```

I use the Eclipse IDE if that helps.

Comment: Do you happen to have an `import` statement for `Supplier` at the top of your source?

Comment: @RealSkeptic no i don't.

Comment: And what is your `package` declaration? You have not actually shown the relevant parts of the source. Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said before, just verify that you are importing `part2.Supplier`.

Another option is to force the full right package structure when you're calling the constructor, like the following:

```
allSuppliers.add(new part2.Supplier(supplierName,supplierAddress,supplierProductList,supplierRegion));
```